# Keyboard Shortcut Not Working with VSIX Installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, shortcut, vsix

I've created a VSIX Package, and I've added the KeyBindings Section in my .vsct file. When I run an experimental instance of Visual Studio, the keyboard shortcut works, but when I actually install the vsix package on my machine, the keyboard shortcut doesn't work, despite the other aspects of the addin working. Is there anything else that would be stopping the shortcut from binding properly?

The Key Bindings

```
<KeyBindings>
        <KeyBinding guid="MyAddinCmdSet" id="cmdidRollback" editor="guidVSStd97" key1="VK_NUMPAD2" mod1="CONTROL"/>         
</KeyBindings>
```

The Command in my vspackage

```
CommandID CommandIDRollback = new CommandID(GuidList.MyAddinCmdSet, (int)PkgCmdIDList.cmdidRollback);
                MenuCommand menuItemRollback = new MenuCommand(MenuItemCallbackRollback, CommandIDRollback);
                mcs.AddCommand( menuItemRollback);
```

Comment: Can you post the VSCT file and package code which handles the command?

Comment: Cool, code has been added.

Answer (score 0):

`key1="VK_NUMPAD2"` is Numeric keypad 2 key, and doesn't work with the "2 K" keyboard , 
you can use key one code  `0x32` , but this shortcut already reserved for `QueryDesigner.Criterria()` so you can't use it.

If you target the Numeric keypad and it doesn't work you have to make sure this shortcut doesn't reserved for visual studio functionality.

For key code see [Virtual-Key Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes).

change your code as the below :

```
<KeyBindings>
   <KeyBinding guid="MyAddinCmdSet" id="cmdidRollback" editor="guidVSStd97" key1="0x32" mod1="CONTROL"/>         
</KeyBindings>
```